# A Question on circles based on co-ordinate geometry.

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

The line $4 x + 3 y – 4 = 0 $ divides the circumference of the circle centred at $ (5,3)$ in the ratio $1:2$ . Then the equation of the circle is?

I tried to solve this problem my taking parametric points but was confused which distance should I take please help me out.

Comment: Then the angle of smaller arc is $120^{\circ}$; so **distance** from the circle **center** to the **line** is twice less then circle **radius**. To find distance, one can use this formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#Line_defined_by_an_equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, given that $4x+3y-4=0$ divides the circumference of the circle in the ratio of $1:2$, the subtended angle at the center is $\dfrac{2\pi}{3}$

The perpendicular distance from the circle of the given line is $5$.

The radius is $10$

So, the equation of the circle is $x^2+y^2-10x-6y-66=0$

[image]

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer

Comment: To make image more realistic, please change line: its "milestone" points are: $(1,0)$ *correct*, $(4,-4)$, $(-2,4)$ etc.

Comment: The algebra is correct but the graphing is not.  The line should have negative slope with same signed coefficients for $x$ and $y$.  The correct version of the line is reflected through the $x$ axis from the one you drew.

Answer (score 0):

We have $4x+3y=4$, so $y=\frac{-4x}{3}+\frac{4}{3}$.

The slopes of perpendicular lines produce $-1$ when multiplied. The line's slope is $\frac{-4}{3}$, so the slope of the perpendicular is $\frac{3}{4}$.

We know $(5,3)$ is on the line.

So $(y-3)=(x-5)\frac{3}{4}$ gives you the equation of the perpendicular.

So $$(x-5)\frac{3}{4}+3=\frac{-4}{3}x+\frac{4}{3}$$

$$\frac{25}{12}x=\frac{25}{12}\implies x=1; y=0 $$

The distance betwen the line and the center is $\sqrt{(5-1)^2+(3-0)^2}=5$

The chords are in a 2:1 ratio. Let $p$ be the radian measure of the shorter, then the other has radian measure $2p$. $3p=2\pi$, so $p=2\pi/3$.

The radius is the hypotenuse of a right triangle made from the line, radius, and the perpendicular. The length of perpendicular between line and center is cosine of half $p$ times the radius. We know the length is $5$ and the cosine is $\frac{1}{2}$, so the radius must be $5$.

$$(x-5)^2+(y-3)^2=10^2=x^2+y^2-10x -6y-66=0$$

Comment: Not the "chords", but the "arcs".